Crystal Report throws 'Connection reset.' on document open
I have RAS setting up and create java web servlet running.
I try to follow the guideline and simply open the unmanaged RPT document. But SDK throws connection reset.
I have try to telnet to the ip and port and it show that it's open. I also have activate the guest account.
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKServerException: Unable to connect to the server: {0}. --- Connection reset----
This is the java code snippet that I used.


import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument;

ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
 reportClientDoc.setReportAppServer("localhost:54300");
 reportClientDoc.open("D:\\SAPBusinessObjects\\tomcat\\webapps\\test.rpt", com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.OpenReportOptions.openAsReadOnly.value());



SAPBusinessObjects.SAP XI 4.0 SP 3
Any help would be much appreciated.

I manage to solve it myself. This usually cause by the different version in client and server package. For me this is the case.
